# where do I set width for product details after removing sidebar block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, product-view

Using Magento 1.9.0.1

On product details page (1 column layout) on the left I have the product image, in center the product title, desciption, attributes, buy button and on the right there is another block space that currently I occupied by a widget Block Product View and in reference it says : block product sidebar right.

when going to static blocks I can make that block not active, but that leaves me with a lot of white space on the product page right side (class = product-view-right hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-3)

how can I get the product details section to also occupy that space so its class goes from  (product-shop col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12) to (product-shop col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12) ?

thanks

Comment: thanks for editing but i'd rather have an answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a 12 column layout you have:
image col-md-4 
details col-md-5 
static block col-md-3

To edit this you would need to locate the file that is calling the static block and remove that call.  Then change the details section from 'col-md-5' to 'col-md-8'. You may need to make similar changes to the tablet and mobile size classes too like changing 'col-sm-6' to 'col-sm-12' or some other option depending on the design you want.

The file you need is most likely app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: Thanks i going to try it... so view.phtml and not the layout.xml

Comment: Glad to hear it!